# How to close all open Tasks before closing the case

Tags: trigger, javascript

When I try to close the case, all tasks under that case should close and I should be able to close the case. I have a javascript button called "Close case" which gives alert if there are open tasks.

[image]

and I've written a trigger to close tasks

```
  public static void deletealltasks (List<case> caseLstt, map<Id, Case> TriggerNewMap){

//create a map of open tasks related to the cases
Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>();

//query open tasks related to cases and populate map
for(Task t : [SELECT Id,status, WhatId FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false AND WhatId IN :TriggerNewMap.keySet()])
{
    t.Status = 'completed';
    taskMap.put(WhatId, t);
}
 }
```

But this is not closing/deleting Tasks. Can we delete all tasks in javascript itself? or any other way?

Answer (score -1):

Anyhow the task will appear in activity History .If you want to clear activity history you have to do it manually .We cannot perform Delete DML operation on activity History

Goto -Setup ->Data Management ->Mass Delete Records -> Select Activity -> And give filter creteria.

thanks